# In Flask convert form POST object into a representation suitable for mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, post, flask, pymongo

I am using Flask and MongoDB. I am trying to convert the content of request.form into something suitable for saving via PyMongo. It seems like something that should come up often enough to have a ready-made solution.

So what Flask give me is something like:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('default', u''), ('required': u'on'), ('name', u'short_text'), ('name', u'another'), ('submit', u'Submit')])
```

And what I am looking to get is something close to this:

```
{
  'default': '',
  'name': ['short_text', 'another'],
  'required': true
}
```

Comment: Why you need that? 

you can access the values as you access in dictionary without converting it.

like d['required'] gives you true in return.

Comment: @Abdul, if you want to loop through the ImmutableNutiDict(), then you can just do like normally dictionary, but if you want use it as a whole as a dict, for example, merge dictionary using z={**x,**y}, then it does not work, the value will have squares around it, like {...,'name':['short_text'],}.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
>>> from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableMultiDict
>>> imd = ImmutableMultiDict([('default', u''), ('required', u'on'), ('name', u'short_text'), ('name', u'another'), ('submit', u'Submit')])
>>> imd.to_dict(flat=False)
>>> {'default': [''], 
'name': ['short_text', 'another'],
'required': ['on'],
'submit': ['Submit']}
```

`.to_dict(flat=False)` is the thing to keep in mind. See the relevant [documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.to_dict)

Comment: Just use the `.to_dict()` method like `imd.to_dict()` instead.  That way every value isn't a list, like in your solution.  Also you won't need to import ImmutableMultiDict

Comment: I would probably update this answer to include what the comment suggests doing. The usage of `.to_dict()` would be the way to go here to remove those values as lists. I would keep your answer as is, but add to it and demonstrate the difference in using `to_dict()`.

Comment: imd.to_dict() isn't appropriate as it loses the duplicate entry

Comment: `imd.to_dict(flat=False) ` is exactly what OP is looking for. See the edited answer above.

Comment: use `imd.to_dict(flat=True)` for get as key/value pair

Comment: `flat=False` is important to get a list of values for a key, instead of a single value. Very important.

Answer (score 32):

The Flask `ImmutableMultiDict` data structure has a built in `to_dict` method.

This knowledge in addition to the Flask `request` object `form` property being an `ImmutableMultiDict` allows for simple handling of a form POST request to MongoDB.

See below for a naive example:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/api/v1/account', methods=['POST'])
def create_account():
    """Create user account"""
    account_dict = request.form.to_dict()

    db.account.insert_one(account_dict)
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use werkzeug's [getlist](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.getlist) to write code like this

```
data = dict((key, request.form.getlist(key)) for key in request.form.keys())
```

Now each key of `data` would be a list which would contain 1 more element. To get results exactly in your format do this

```
data = dict((key, request.form.getlist(key) if len(request.form.getlist(key)) > 1 else request.form.getlist(key)[0]) for key in request.form.keys())
```

Now this is inefficient because for each key there are 3 calls to `request.form.getlist(key)`. You can write a loop and get around it.

Answer (score 17):

`request.form.to_dict()` would yield what you need

Answer (score 4):

Comparison of `dict()` and `.to_dict()` method before and after python version 3.6.

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableMultiDict
imd = ImmutableMultiDict([('default', u''), ('required', u'on'), ('name', u'short_text'), ('name', u'another'), ('submit', u'Submit')])
```

Till python3.5

```
dict(imd)
#output: {'default': [''], 'required': ['on'], 'name': ['short_text', 'another'], 'submit': ['Submit']}

imd.to_dict(flat=false)
#output: {'default': [''], 'required': ['on'], 'name': ['short_text', 'another'], 'submit': ['Submit']}

imd.to_dict(flat=True) # or imd.to_dict() 
#output: {'default': '', 'required': 'on', 'name': 'short_text', 'submit': 'Submit'}
```

Thus,

```
dict(imd) == imd.to_dict(flat=False)
#output: True
```

From python3.6 onwards

```
dict(imd)
#output: {'default': '', 'required': 'on', 'name': 'short_text', 'submit': 'Submit'}

imd.to_dict(flat=false)
#output: {'default': [''], 'required': ['on'], 'name': ['short_text', 'another'], 'submit': ['Submit']}

imd.to_dict(flat=True) # or imd.to_dict() 
#output: {'default': '', 'required': 'on', 'name': 'short_text', 'submit': 'Submit'}
```

Thus,

```
dict(imd) == imd.to_dict(flat=False)
#output: False
```

Using `.to_dict()` with `flat=True/False` is a safer option.

Comment: This was sooo helpful. I resurrected a 2-year old project and a bunch of tests were broken and was wondering how the heck is the site even running.... turns out the running site is using `dict()` and 3.5. Switching to 3.6 and `flat=False`.

Comment: Running ```dict(ImmutableMultiDict)``` on Python 3.7 windows 10 worked fine for me. When i deployed the project to Windows Server 2016 on Python 3.7 ```dict(ImmutableMultiDict)``` returned dict values as a list. I had to use ```.to_dict()```.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> from werkzeug.datastructures import ImmutableMultiDict
>>> so = ImmutableMultiDict([('default', u''), ('required', u'on'), ('name', u'short_text'), ('name', u'another'), ('submit', u'Submit')])

# Most earlier answers have comments suggesting so.to_dict()
# It doesn't work, duplicates are lost like in a normal dict
>>> so.to_dict()
{'default': '', 'required': 'on', 'name': 'short_text', 'submit': 'Submit'}

# The response by Vb407 is better but litters lists everywhere
>>> dso = dict(so)
{'default': [''], 'required': ['on'], 'name': ['short_text', 'another'], 'submit': ['Submit']}

# We can achieve the requested state by cleaning this up
>>> { k: dso[k][0] if len(dso[k]) <= 1 else dso[k] for k in dso }
{'default': '', 'required': 'on', 'name': ['short_text', 'another'], 'submit': 'Submit'}
```

Comment: This is best answer. Especially the last method that differentiates between list and strings is perfect.